# Filtering a child collection inside a parent collection

Tags: c#, linq

Is the following scenario possible using LINQ.  I have a class like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }        
    public List<MyClass2> MyData { get; set; }
    public List<MyClass2> OtherData { get; set; }
}
```

I have a list of these and I want to filter `MyData` based on a criteria; for example (doesn't work):

```
List<MyClass> myData = GetData();

var myDataFiltered = myData
    .Where(d => d.Id == 3)
    .SelectMany(d => d.Where(m => m.MyData.SomeProperty == somevalue), d);
```

I want the result to be a `List<MyClass>`, but to only contain the original MyData elements where `SomeProperty == somevalue`.

Comment: Sorry, it specifically doesn't work because it's just an illustration of what I'm trying to achieve.  I thought posting some pseudo C# would illustrate my point better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to reassign property in LINQ select function.
Something like this:

```
var myDataFiltered = myData
.Where(d => d.Id == 3)
.Select(d => {
    d.MyData = d.MyData.Where(m => m.SomeProperty == somevalue).ToList();
    return d;
 });
```

Comment: This won't compile assuming that `MyData` really is a `List<T>`.

Comment: True, i forgot obvious ToList() call :). I focused on showing how to write pure LINQ call. Thanks for pointing it

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var myDataFiltered = myData
    .Where(d => d.Id == 3)
    .Select(x => new MyClass()
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        MyData = x?.MyData.Where(y => y.SomeProperty == somevalue).ToList(),
        OtherData = x.OtherData
    })
    .Where(x => x.MyData != null && x.MyData.Count > 0)
    .ToList();
```

It creates new instances of `MyClass` that only contains the queried `MyClass2` objects. You probably don't want to modify the original instances in a query.

Answer (score 1):

```
var myDataFiltered = myData
.Where(d => d.Id == 3)
.SelectMany(d => d.MyData).Where(t=>t.SomeProperty == somevalue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember LINQ query uses lambda expressions to query for data. So what that means is that, you should use from to get the data. Now there are two key things that you should note. When you don't use FROM as shown below:

```
// LINQ Query Syntax
var result = from s in stringList
             where s.Contains("Tutorials") 
             select s;
```

The operators `FROM`, `WHERE` and `SELECT` ensure that the query returns the data, into variable result. See screenshot below

[image: LINQ Query Syntax]

However in your situation you are using LINQ method syntax which means that we use extension methods to return results as shown below:

[image]

Therefore you query will look like as follows:

```
List<MyClass> myData = GetData();
var myDataFiltered = myData.Where(d => d.Id == 3)
                           .SelectMany(d => d.Where(m => m.MyData.SomeProperty == somevalue), d)
                           .ToList();
```

I hope the two methods make sense. That you are querying list object or an `IEnumerable` list using LINQ query syntax or using LINQ operations method.